# How to fetch data from this json

Tags: ios, arrays, json

I want this data to be displayed in the tableview . can anyone tell me how to take data in the dictionary or array and display in the table? the data is shown as under

I want to display `city` and `custno`

```
{
"Status": 200,
"data": [
    {
        "dispatch": "11111",
        "locname": "Sample Company Location 1",
        "add1": "226 Engleman Street",
        "city": "Bardstown",
        "state": "KY",
        "zip": "40004",
        "contacts": [
            {
                "id": "1",
                "custno": "0000235",
                "locno": "00001",
                "salutation": "Mr.",
                "jobtitle": "IT Manager",
                "locktime": "",
                "lockby": ""
            },
            {
                "id": "11",
                "custno": "0000235",
                "locno": "00001",
                "contact": "Greg C",

                "extension": "205",
                "salutation": "Mr. ",
                "jobtitle": "President",
                "locktime": null,
                "lockby": null
            },
            {
                "id": "12",
                "custno": "0000235",
                "locno": "00001",

                "extension": "206",
                "salutation": "Mr.",
                "jobtitle": "Parts Manager",
                "locktime": null,
                "lockby": null
            },
            {
                "id": "13",
                "custno": "0000235",
                "locno": "00001",

                "extension": "202",
                "salutation": "Mr.",
                "jobtitle": "Service Manager",
                "locktime": "",
                "lockby": ""
            }
        ],
        "locationnotes": "5/20/2010 9:32:06 PM - Updated Information1111111",
        "custno": "0000235",
        "locno": "00001",
        "calledinby": "Teresa",
        "serviceagrno": "",
        "dispatchnotes": "This is a test dispatch",
        "pastcustomernotes": "",
        "pasttechnotes": [],
        "status": "Pending",
        "locationimage": "/images/content/2t_1318687848_100x100.gif",
        "pmstatus": "Yes"
    },
    {
        "dispatch": "4",
        "locname": "Sample Company Location 1",
        "add1": "226 Engleman Street",
        "city": "Bardstown",
        "state": "KY",
        "zip": "40004",
        "contacts": [
            {
                "id": "1",
                "custno": "0000235",
                "locno": "00001",

                "extension": "200",
                "salutation": "Mr.",
                "jobtitle": "IT Manager",
                "locktime": "",
                "lockby": ""
            },
            {
                "id": "11",
                "custno": "0000235",
                "locno": "00001",
                "phonefax": "555-555-1002",
                "extension": "205",
                "salutation": "Mr. ",
                "jobtitle": "President",
                "locktime": null,
                "lockby": null
            },
            {
                "id": "12",
                "custno": "0000235",
                "locno": "00001",
                "extension": "206",
                "salutation": "Mr.",
                "jobtitle": "Parts Manager",
                "locktime": null,
                "lockby": null
            },
            {
                "id": "13",
                "custno": "0000235",
                "locno": "00001",

                "extension": "202",
                "salutation": "Mr.",
                "jobtitle": "Service Manager",
                "locktime": "",
                "lockby": ""
            }
        ],
        "locationnotes": "5/20/2010 9:32:06 PM - Updated Information1111111",
        "custno": "0000235",
        "locno": "00001",
        "calledinby": "Teresa",
        "serviceagrno": null,
        "dispatchnotes": "11/3/2011 7:59 - This is a sample ATM call.",
        "pastcustomernotes": "",
        "pasttechnotes": [],
        "status": "Pending",
        "locationimage": "/images/content/2t_1318687848_100x100.gif",
        "pmstatus": "No"
    },
    {
        "dispatch": "5",
        "locname": "Sample Company Location 1",
        "add1": "226 Engleman Street",
        "city": "Bardstown",
        "state": "KY",
        "zip": "40004",
        "contacts": [
            {
                "id": "1",
                "custno": "0000235",
                "locno": "00001",
                "contact": "Michael B",
                "email": "michael@bonzahouse.com",
                "phoneoffice": "502-555-1000",
                "phonemobile": "502-555-0769",
                "phonefax": "555-555-1002",
                "extension": "200",
                "salutation": "Mr.",
                "jobtitle": "IT Manager",
                "locktime": "",
                "lockby": ""
            },
            {
                "id": "11",
                "custno": "0000235",
                "locno": "00001",

                "extension": "205",
                "salutation": "Mr. ",
                "jobtitle": "President",
                "locktime": null,
                "lockby": null
            },
            {
                "id": "12",
                "custno": "0000235",
                "locno": "00001",
                "extension": "206",
                "salutation": "Mr.",
                "jobtitle": "Parts Manager",
                "locktime": null,
                "lockby": null
            },
            {
                "id": "13",
                "custno": "0000235",
                "locno": "00001",
                "extension": "202",
                "salutation": "Mr.",
                "jobtitle": "Service Manager",
                "locktime": "",
                "lockby": ""
            }
        ],
        "locationnotes": "5/20/2010 9:32:06 PM - Updated Information1111111",
        "custno": "0000235",
        "locno": "00001",
        "calledinby": "",
        "serviceagrno": null,
        "dispatchnotes": "",
        "pastcustomernotes": "",
        "pasttechnotes": [],
        "status": "Pending",
        "locationimage": "/images/content/2t_1318687848_100x100.gif",
        "pmstatus": "Yes"
    }
]
```

}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to read that into an `NSDictionary` with either `NSJSONSerialization` (only available in iOS 5 and later) or another JSON framework (I recommend TouchJSON - https://github.com/TouchCode/TouchJSON).

Here are examples:

NSJSONSerialization:

```
NSString *jsonString = <JSON_STRING>;
NSData *jsonData = [jsonString dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
NSError *error = nil;
NSDictionary *dictionary = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:jsonData
                                                           options:0 
                                                             error:&error];
```

TouchJSON:

```
NSString *jsonString = <JSON_STRING>;
NSData *jsonData = [jsonString dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
NSError *error = nil;
NSDictionary *dictionary = [[CJSONDeserializer deserializer] 
                             deserializeAsDictionary:jsonData 
                                               error:&error];
```

Once you have the dictionary you can then extract the information you want. In your case it looks like you want to grab the `data` which is an array of objects. I assume you then want to show something about those objects in a table. So here's the start of that code to get you going and then you should be able to figure out the rest:

```
NSArray *data = [dictionary objectForKey:@"data"];

// Then for each data object, you can get at say its `locname' attribute to show in a cell like so
NSString *locname = [[data objectAtIndex:i] objectForKey:@"locname"];
```

Comment: When using NSJSONSerialization, one should probably use "options:kNilOptions" instead of "options:0". Both work, but the former seems a bit more readable to my eye (and is what Apple recommends).